# Remove element in array by value | MongoDB | NodeJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a mongoDB with a collection called users. Each element has a usrName, UserID, token, and then 3 arrays which are friends, incoming and outgoing (all of them relative to 'friends'). Im looking for something like:

`db.collection('users').find({user:"some userID"}).update` or something similar.

I expect the search for the correct element (by the id) and then remove some element from the 'incoming' array by the value. (its a string array)

here is the DB structure[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The update would look something like this:

`db.collection('users').updateOne({user: "some userID"}, {$pull: { incoming: "removeThisValue" }})`

`$pull` takes an object which describes the array field you are pulling from and the criteria you are using to remove it. Since you said it's a string array you'll be looking for equality. But just note that you could also use mongodb operators such as `$gte`, `$lt` and others if working with different values.

If you were removing multiple values from the array at once:

`db.collection('users').updateOne({user: "some userID"}, {$pull: { incoming: { $in: ["removeMe", "removeMeToo"] } }})`

Its also worth noting if you ever have an array of documents you could also target specific key/values. Let's say a user has an array of hobbies where each hobby has "title" and "timePerWeek" keys. We could remove the hobby with the title of "Gaming" like this:

`db.collection('users').updateOne({user: "some userID"}, {$pull: { hobbies: {title: "Gaming"} }})`